# how to find two short numbers in between another short numbers in C#

Tags: c#

I am having two short numbers  20101, 20141  if i pass 20121 and 20131 then it should return  it is available with in the range.  if i pass 20081 and 20091 then it should return false, same for 20142 to 20154.

how to find in between for two short numbers.

```
bool TestRange (int numberToCheck, int bottom, int top)
{
  return (numberToCheck >= bottom && numberToCheck <= top);
}
```

tried the above but it is working as expected. because in my case i want to check two short numbers in another two short numbers. how to do it

Comment: Well.. just call it twice then!?

Answer (score 2):

Change the signature to `bool TestRange (int[] numbersToCheck, int bottom, int top)` and iterate `numbersToCheck` and return as required

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed to use something like that way too often and I'm lazy, I've written an extension method, to check if any integer is between two values.

```
public static class IntExtensions
{
    public static bool Between(this int value, int lowerBound, int upperBound)
    {
        return value >= lowerBound && value <= upperBound;
    }
}
```

That way you can easily use it with LinQ as

```
return Array.All(x => x.Between(integer, integer)); // All numbers must be in range.

return Array.Any(x => x.Between(integer, integer)); // At least one number must be in range.
```

Or just return the numbers that match the constraint as a new array:

```
return Array.Where(x => x.Between(integer, integer)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In general case with *many* (arbitrary number) items to test, I suggest signature modification and *Linq*:

```
// If you want to pass many items, pass IEnumerable<T> 
bool TestRange(IEnumerable<int> numbersToCheck, int bottom, int top) {
  if (null == numberToCheck)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("numbersToCheck"); // or return true or false... 

  return numbersToCheck.All(item => item >= bottom && top <= item);
}

...

if (TestRange(new int[] {20121, 20131}, 20101, 20141)) {...}
```